# Getting PHP variable into Database

Tags: php, mysql

getting : Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string... from the following code:

```
$url = "{$row['url']}";

$embed_info = json_decode($client->get('oembed', array('url' => $url)));
$sql="INSERT INTO persons (iframe) VALUES('$embed_info')";
```

How do I get $embed_info to work as a string and go into my database nicely?

Comment: well, do a `var_dump($embed_info)` and see what you're trying to insert. it's obviously not a plain string. given it's stdclass, whatever you're getting is decoding to an object, not a string.

Comment: Are you trying to store the JSON?  If so, don't do json_decode first, which will return an object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this:

```
$embed_info = json_decode($client->get('oembed', array('url' => $url)));
```

Assuming the `$client->get` call returns JSON (a string), that may be what you want to store.  Once you call `json_decode` on that JSON, `$embed_info` is then an object (the decoded JSON). You can't then do something like `$sql = "...$embed_info...";` because PHP will attempt to implicitly try to convert the *Object* into a String.

If you want to just store the JSON, skip the `json_decode` call.

Comment: so is just $embed_info = $client->get('oembed', array('url' => $url)); going to be a solution?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know *what you're trying to store*.  IF you want to store the JSON response as a string, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is a good practice or if it fits on your needs but you can serialize the object and encode it with base64 (for commas, and other chars)

```
$embed_info = json_decode($client->get('oembed', array('url' => $url)));
$data = base64_encode(serialize($embed_info));
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (iframe) VALUES ('{$data}')";
```

Later you can retrieve the object:

```
$sql = "SELECT iframe FROM persons WHERE <the where>";
// ... execute the query and fetch in $row
$embed_info = unserialize(base64_decode($row['iframe']));
// Now in $embed_info you get back the object 
// Note that the object's class must be loaded before do that
```

Comment: Op has the object in String form already (it's JSON).  Why decode it, then serialize it, then encode it just so you can store it as a String...only to have to do the reverse when pulling it out of the DB?

Comment: okay the code stored in my database is now crazy, i really just want to store useable iframe embed codes. Any ideas?

Comment: @Madbreaks perhaps I misunderstood the question, but if he is asking how to insert an object into a db (not json, directly the object) you can do this way. But as I say in the post, don't think is a good practice.